# Is it possible to monitor (detect, keep track etc) basic types of I/O activity inside the JVM?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Is there any API or library that allows user to create some kind of report about actions performed by a program running inside a JVM instance? What I mean is something like JVM/system calls interception with further classification according to the type of activity, for example, `DiskWrite`, `DiskRead`, `NetworkWrite`, `NetworkRead`, `Wait` (is that really an activity?) and so on. Detecting periods of intensive CPU usage etc. would be useful too. If some amount of writing native code is required, detailed answers covering the topic are appreciated as well.

Comment: You might consider looking into this http://www.jvmmonitor.org/ JVM Monitor for eclipse

Comment: @cdshines-Won't java Visual VM which comes with java_jdk help!

Comment: @shekharsuman, I couldn't find nothing pertaining to disk statistics in API docs. Could you point me more precisely?

Answer (score 1):

Use [SIGAR API by Hyperic](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home). It provides Memory, CPU, Disk, Load-Average, Network Interface info and metrics, Process Table information, Route info, etc.

And all this staff under Apache License, Version 2.0.